# Problema para construir PDF en LaTeX usando Linux

Tags: linux, latex

Intento hacer un documento de PDF a través de la linea de comandos de linux.

Para esto tengo ya previamente escrito un archivo `.tex` el cual ejecuta perfectamente en `TexMaker`, para generar el PDF uso el comando

```
pdflatex archivo.tex
```

Este es el código de LaTeX

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish, activeacute]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/root/Imágenes/} }
\colorlet{LIME GREEN}{green}

\title{\textbf{\textcolor{green}{Tipo de vulnerabilidad \\
\large SPF BAD CONFIGURATION }}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

El protocolo SPF (Sender Policy Framework) es un protocolo empleado para ...

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{funcionamientoSPF}
\centering
\caption{Funcionamienot de SPF}
\end{figure}
....

%\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\centering Opci'on & {\centering Descripci'on} \\
\hline 
\hline   %<--------- linea 63
+all & Indica que se autoriza el env'io de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro\\ 
\hline
~all & Indica que se autoriza el env'io de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro SPF, recomendando los declarados en el mismo. Es probable que entre como spam si el rando no est'a bien definido\\ 
\hline
-all & Indica que mo se autoriza explicitamte el env'io de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro SPF\\ \hline
?all & "No se puede decir nada de la validaci'on", el correo es aceptado\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}

Un registro SPF cuidadosamente dise'~nado reducir'a la probabilidad de que el nombre de dominicio se falsifique y evite que los mensajes se marquen como spam antes de que lleguen a sus destinatarios.
\end{document}
```

Y al ejecutar por línea de comandos me da el siguiente error:

```
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

</root/Imágenes/funcionamientoSPF.png, id=1, 660.96938pt x 477.28313pt>
<use /root/Imágenes/funcionamientoSPF.png> [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts     /map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
              {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth\futurelet...
l.63 \hline
?
```

¿Alguien podría darme alguna idea de por qué obtengo ese error? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Parece que el error te da en una línea que puede que no hayas incluido en el código de la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias la linea 63 hace referencia al ultimo \hline del bloque de la creacion de tabla

    %\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    \centering Opci'on & {\centering Descripci'on} \\
    \hline 
    \hline
    +all & Indica que se autoriza el env'io de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro\\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al compilar el código no me arrojó ningún error en la línea que indica en el comentario (63). De todas formas para evitar cualquier error con esa doble línea horizontal, es preferible solo dejar una `\hline`. Asimismo, hice un par de cambios en su código para centrar los títulos y ponerlos en `negrita`, además de unas correcciones de formato y otras menores que explicaré a continuación.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\colorlet{LIME GREEN}{green}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}

\title{\textbf{\textcolor{green}{Tipo de vulnerabilidad \\
\large SPF BAD CONFIGURATION }}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\noindent El protocolo SPF (Sender Policy Framework) es un protocolo empleado para...
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{funcionamientoSPF}
\centering
\caption{Funcionamiento de SPF}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Opción}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Descripción}}                                                                                                                                                               \\ \hline\hline
\verb|+all|      & Indica que se autoriza el envío de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
\verb|~all|      & Indica que se autoriza el envío de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro SPF, recomendando los declarados en el mismo. Es probable que entre como spam si el rango no está bien definido \\ \hline
\verb|-all|      & Indica que no se autoriza explícitamente el envío de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro SPF                                                                                           \\ \hline
\verb|?all|      & "No se puede decir nada de la validación", el correo es aceptado                                                                                                                                        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\bigskip
Un registro SPF cuidadosamente diseñado reducirá la probabilidad de que el nombre de domicilio se falsifique y evite que los mensajes se marquen como spam antes de que lleguen a sus destinatarios.

\end{document}
```

> Cambios realizados:
>
> 1. Por cuestiones prácticas, eliminé los paquetes que eran superfluos para el propósito de la respuesta con el fin de minimizar el código y simplificar.
> 2. Añadí `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`, que es el paquete para acentos y caracteres como `ñ` en Español, que no requiere el paquete `babel`. Como puede ver en el código, todas las palabras están acentuadas sin problema, además que la separación de las mismas se da según las reglas del idioma castellano.
> 3. Añadí también `\author{}` y `\date{}`, pues me originaba un error con la fecha por un lado, y por otro, no vi necesario indicar el nombre del autor. Quedará a criterio suyo.
> 4. La instrucción `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}` en el preámbulo es para cambiar el título de las figuras en el ambiente `figure` , ya que por defecto es en Inglés.
> 5. Con respecto a la tabla, la introduje en el ambiente `table`, que es una figura flotante que puede manejarse entre el texto de la página. El parámetro `[htbp]` es el recomendable siempre.
> 6. Como puede ver la tabla usa `\multicolumn{}{}{}` que en este caso funciona para centrar solo esa celda del título.
> 7. Centré la promera columna y metí los *comandos "all"* entre `\verb| |` para dejarlo en modo `verbatim`, muy usual tipográficamente cuando se trata de escribir comandos "crudos".
> 8. El uso correcto de las comillas es ``` `` texto'' ``` en lugar de encerrarlo en las típicas `"texto"`.
> 9. También hice otras correcciones menores en algunas palabras que tenían errores.

---

Por otro lado, hay otras observaciones que me permito hacerle con respecto a la presentacion de las tablas (según las convenciones tipográficas), entre otras. Y debo aclarar que esto ya es una cuestión opcional: como recomendación extendida en el mundillo de la tipografía, se suele evitar a toda costa el uso de líneas verticales en las tablas. Ya por cuestiones estilísticas o de formato, se recomienda prescindir de ellas. Este uso es el que por convención se ha tomado ahora en los textos que contienen estos elementos, y no se puede negar que esa simplicidad le da un carácter muy estético al texto. Acá le adjunto el código de su tabla con estos cambios.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cp{10cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Opción}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Descripción}}                                                                                                                                                                \\ \midrule
\verb|+all|      & Indica que se autoriza el envío de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro                                                                                                                 \\[1ex]
\verb|~all|      & Indica que se autoriza el envío de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro SPF, recomendando los declarados en el mismo. Es probable que entre como spam si el rango no está bien definido \\[1ex]
\verb|-all|      & Indica que no se autoriza explícitamente el envío de correo desde servidores no declarados en el registro SPF                                                                                           \\[1ex]
\verb|?all|      & ``No se puede decir nada de la validación'', el correo es aceptado                                                                                                                                        \\[1ex] \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**P.D**: NO es recomendable ponerle color a los títulos.